# Textblock in a listview doesn't show the bind data - WPF XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, mvvm, data-binding

I'm trying to bind the data with text block in a listview but it doesn't show the data. However, when I run the application, I can see the list is created but it display the empty data. See the empty list of data in the below image:

[image: Application: Bind data do not show]

---

Here's my XAML code:

```
<ListView Margin="20,0,0,20" x:Name="listView_attachedFiles">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Width="100" Text="{Binding AttachedFiles, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}">
                <Hyperlink>
                </Hyperlink>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

---

Here's the C# Code

```
public class ListviewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<string> _attachedfiles;
    public ObservableCollection<string> AttachedFiles
    {
        get { return _attachedfiles; }
        set
        {

            _attachedfiles = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("AttachedFiles");

        }
    }

    public ListviewModel()
    {
        AttachedFiles = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    /// <summary>
    /// Raises this object's PropertyChanged event.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="propertyName">The property that has a new value.</param>
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

---

Here's is how I'm populating the data:

```
// I'm calling this method to attach the list of filenames       
    private void ExecuteMethod_AttachFile(object Parameter)
    {

        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.Multiselect = true;
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            AttachedFileLocation = ofd.FileNames.ToList();

            // adding bind data to the list of viewmodel: adding attachefile names
            foreach (var file in AttachedFileLocation)
            {
                FileInfo info = new FileInfo(file);
                DMS_Form.Instance.ListofViewModel.AttachedFiles.Add(info.Name + "  X");
            }

        }
    }
```

---

Here's is how I'm attaching the itemssource reference in the constructor of the WPF Form.

```
//Binding the list of attached files with the listview
listView_attachedFiles.ItemsSource = ListofViewModel.AttachedFiles;
```

Please help me figure out where I'm making the mistake. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you

Ali

Answer (score 0):

With some hours of research, I realized there was a bit problem with my code. The solution is to **first** define data context in the WPF Form constructor method i.e

```
listView_attachedFiles.DataContext = ListofViewModel;
```

second update this XAML code

```
<TextBlock Width="100" Text="{Binding AttachedFiles, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}">
```

with this XAML code.

```
<TextBlock Width="100" Text="{Binding}">
```

Now save, and build the application, run it.